# Pandas dataframe : sample() function resets indexes?

Tags: python, pandas

Please consider a panda dataframe `final_df` with 142457 rows correctly indexed:

```
0
1 
2
3
4
...
142452
142453
142454
142455
142456
```

I create / sample a new df `data_test_for_all_models`  from this one:

```
data_test_for_all_models = final_df.copy().sample(frac=0.1, random_state=786)
```

A few indexes:

```
2235
118727
23291`
```

Now I drop rows from `final_df` with indexes in `data_test_for_all_models` :

```
final_df = = final_df.drop(data_test_for_all_models.index)
```

If I check a few indexes present in `final_df` :

```
final_df.iloc[2235]
```

returns wrongly a row.

I think it's a problem of reset indexes but which function does it: drop(), sample()?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using [`.iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) which provides integer-based indexing. You are getting the row number `2235`, not the row with index `2235`.

For that, you should use [`.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
final_df.loc[2235]
```

And you should get a `KeyError`.

Comment: Exact you right, sorry.